# Wordpress slow to load on initial load. Subsequent loads go quicker (caching disabled)

Tags: wordpress, performance

I'm having issues with a basic Wordpress install. I'm using Chrome, in incognito mode, so as to disable caching during testing.

What occurs is if I visit the site it will take roughly 10-30 seconds to load the initial time. Subsequent loads are usually around 2-5 seconds (remember I've disabled caching so this isn't an issue related to that).

The vast majority of the load time is on the HTML page and NOT on the additional assets.

If I wait about 15 minutes and load the page again, it will take 10-30 seconds. If I hit reload after that, it will again load in 2-5 seconds.

**Here's an image of the network panel in Chrome - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRvEI.jpg**

Comment: What's the link to your site?

Comment: Can you give more information. Are you using any caching on db level? what's your site?

Comment: Here's the URL - http://www.treeviews.com/

I did try W3 super cache with database caching on but that did not make a difference. I found the page level caching to be too aggressive and thought it would confuse our Wordpress editors.

Answer (score 1):

98% chance this is a host issue with their slow server and network latency. Looks like Rackspace, and DNS is a private nameserver vermeer.com. Talk to them.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up talking to Rackspace. I was using the W3 Total Cache Wordpress plugin and they let me know that they've had issues with that and that I should switch to WP-SuperCache. That seems to be working better.